# Direct Java casting using obj1=obj2;

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, reference

There are three classes

```
class Flower{}
class Violet extends Flower{}
class Gardenia extends Flower{}
```

and the main class is this

```
    class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flower f1 = new Flower();
        Flower f2 = new Gardenia();
        Violet v = new Violet();
        Gardenia g1 = new Gardenia();
        Gardenia g2 = new Gardenia();
        g1 =f1; 
        f1 = g1;
        g1=v;
        v=(Violet)f2;
        g2=f1;
        g1=f2;
    }

}
```

The question is how for example g1 =f1; could be written differently? Assigning an object reference to another directly looks confusing. In this code we are asked to do proper casting and comment those lines where we can 't do anything (We don't want ClassCastEcxeption). For example in line `f1=g1;` we could say `Flower f1=g1;`.

Comment: Do you mean `g1 = (Gardenia)f2;`? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean after assigning `f1=g1; ` , could we write this assignment like this `Flower f1= new Gardenia();`? And after that, the f1 would be an instance of Flower type pointin to a `Gardenia();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you want to know, but your code can't compile because you can't assign g1 = f1 since f1 is an object of the superclass Flower, while g1 is of the subclass. You can do the opposite if you want.

To be more clear and using an easy language, if Flower have some methods, all its subclass will have the same methods plus some more methods that you can declare. So if you take a Flower object and you try to use it as a Gardenia object, there could be some particular methods that you can't use, since a Flower object have "less" things than a Gardenia object.

I suggest you to read more about the subject, like for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

EDIT: you can use Flower f1 = new Gardenia() instead of f1 = g1 and you'll have the same result.

Here case by case:

```
    g1 =f1; //desn't work
    f1 = g1; // now f1 points to g1 and you can treat the object g1 like a flower object
    g1=v; // doesn't work
    v=(Violet)f2; //desn't work
    g2=f1; //doesn't work, but since now f1 has a Gardenia object, you can make it work doing g2 = (Gardenia) f1 
    g1=f2; //doesn't work
```

Comment: I know about having a superclass `type`  holding a subclass instance that i won't be able to use some methods of subclass. The direct pointing is confusing me. I want a clear assignment like `Flower f1= new Gardenia();` to understand well what will happen. In the code i posted there is no such thing. So I'm asking after each correct (direct) assignment from code above what will be the type and what instance will point to.